# How can I solve model.frame.default? Could it be a data problem?

Tags: r, deep-learning, neural-network, forecasting

I am trying to run the following code when trying to build the neural network:

```
bank.nnet <- nnet(DLRSN ~ . -CUSIP -FYEAR, data = bank.train, size = 1, maxit = 500, type='class')
prob.nnet = predict(bank.nnet, bank.test)
```

Whenever I run it I receive the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor CUSIP has new levels 00036110, 00078110, 00079X10, 00086T10, 00088630, 00088U10, 00089310, 00089N10, 00095510, 00095710, 00097310, 00100410, 00100T10, 00103110, 00105810, 00108410, 00120410, 00130H10, 00132010, 00143T10, 00154710, 00162710, 00162H10, (...)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Best, Emily

I think there is some issues with the amount of data, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Generally the problem here is that there are levels in your test set that aren't present in your training set. You can filter your test set to exclude observations where CUSIP has one of the new levels, or do something to make sure that your train/test set are balanced on levels ...